How to populate a matrix assigning values based on placeholders?
I have a matrix populated with letters as placeholders. I need these letters to be substituted with integers ranging from 0 to 9. Each of these integers will correspond to one digit of a number formed from the sequence of digits in each row. This resulting number must satisfy certain conditions. I have placed the letters in a specific pattern because the same letters must ultimatly correspond to the same integers/digits.
matrix = np.array([['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
                   ['A', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'F'],
                   ['A', 'E', 'E', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'F']])

My approach was to create a loop that assigns an integer from 0 to 9 to each element of the array/row, accounting for all possible combinations. Then, I check if these combinations satisfy the conditions imposed on the resulting number from that row (with a separate function that I have defined separately to check this condition).
My problem is that I am unable to generalize this loop. I don't know how to check within the loop if the placeholder is the same so that the same value can be assigned to all elements in the array that share the same placeholder.
row1 = matrix[0]
i = 0
while i < 10:
    row1[0] = row1[1] = row1[2] = i
    j = 0
    while j < 10:
        row1[3] = row1[4] = row1[5] = j
        k = 0
        while k < 10:
            row1[6] = row1[7] = k
            y = 0
            while y < 10:
                row1[8] = row1[9] = row1[10] = y
                l = 0
                num = 0
                while l < 11:
                    num = num + pow(10, 10 - l) * int(row1[l])
                    l += 1
                if rule1(num):
                    return num
                y += 1
            k += 1
        j += 1
    i += 1


what is the expected output?

Why use while loops instead of for i in range(10):?

I would create a dictionary holding the mapping from placeholder to value. Then you can loop through the matrix, replacing each placeholder with the corresponding values from the dictionary.

The number that should correspond to the first row for example should be a square (the code that I have shown as an example is the loop corresponding to the first row of the matrix). While the condition for the second row is that the resulting number is a palindrom. I'm expecting as an outcome number that satisfies those conditions and respects the pattern described by the letters.
